# Do methods affect the size of my objects?

Tags: .net, methods, memory-management

In .NET, do the number of methods or the size of the methods (i.e., amount of code)  within an object affect the amount of memory the object uses when it is instantiated?

EXAMPLE:
Will an object with 3 int properties and 1 method take up more memory than an object with 3 int properties and 20 methods?

If "yes", do static methods take up less memory?

Please note: I realise that actually calling a method might instantiate other objects or variables that will use memory - my question simply relates to how much memory they use after calling the constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  Methods take up memory but that's *very* little.  The method table as well as the code generated for the method is shared by every instance of the object.

Comment: So methods do take up memory, but it is shared between objects of the same type? (i.e., The "method memory" use for 1 object is the same as the "method memory" use of 100 objects of the same type?)

Answer (score 2):

> Will an object with 3 int properties
>   and 1 method take up more memory than
>   an object with 3 int properties and 20
>   methods?

The answer is no. Methods aren't part of any particular instance. They *belong* to the type.